How can I boot from a full shutdown, without WoL, if the BIOS doesn't support it?
My daily-driver Windows PC has for years powered up automatically every morning, so that it's completely ready to go with all my apps launched by the time I walk into my home office.  To do this required a simple change of the BIOS to set the boot timer.
I just got a new work machine, and its BIOS doesn't have any such feature that I can find (Asrock z790 pro rs wifi).  Is there any way I can schedule this machine to wake up from a full power-down state, on a schedule?
To be clear:

I don't want to sleep rather than shut down
I don't want to use WoL from another machine (defeats the purpose)
I see no boot scheduling options in the BIOS but if anyone knows otherwise, I'm all ears


Your motherboard's Support section has a link to the BIOS setup guide.
Page 72 indicates to go to Advanced -> ACPI Configuration and configure RTC Power On. Options are Enable, Disable, By OS.
Enable should then provide options for setting the time.

Hmmmm thanks, I'll go digging for it again, couldn't find it last time.

Bingo!  Thank you so much!  I was looking for something with the same/similar name as on my old machine, and this is totally different, so I missed it.  Looks like this will do the trick so thanks again!

So I set it to boot at 5am this morning, and it did not do so.  Don't know why it failed, will have to do some experimenting apparently.  I'll post when hopefully I figure out what the trick is and re-mark the answer.
